# Modifier button is not there?

Tags: modifiers

I've seen videos of people using blender and using the modify button but the wrench icon isn't there for me?

[image]

Comment: You've selected an empty, it can't accept modifiers

Comment: what does that mean, can you go more in to depth?

Comment: you can only apply a modifier to an object, but you haven't selected an object in your 3D scene, you have selected an empty, so the modifier tab is not displayed, you need to select an object in your 3D view

Comment: i did select a model though

Comment: https://ibb.co/VCYBrPz

Comment: how do i find non empty models because all of them are empty for me /:

Comment: what you show seems to be a collection instance, if you want to give a modifier to one of its object, go into the collection and select the object

Comment: @rowan The dark orange outline indicates the object is selected but its not the active object. Click on it again or select it from the hierarchy and it should turn into a bright orange outline, then you will be able to apply modifiers

Comment: CTRL A > Make Instance Real